# How to create logo and icons to use in web page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Been looking into responsive web design lately, and to practice I've made a very simple "application" which adapts to the screen size of the browser. Everything works as expected, but now I'd like to spice up the interface.

My intention is to create a logo and perhaps some icons too. I've downloaded GIMP and I was thinking of using it. Then it struck me, is that the proper way to proceed?

Is GIMP a good choice? Or, could that be achieved with the functions in HTML5, like canvas and stuff like that. Or how do you normally do and with what tools?

I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: you might be interested in this http://smashinghub.com/ultimate-responsive-web-design-toolkit.htm

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you using [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) , i hope you enjoy working with it, however normal graphics that you want ever be accessible for wide range of your visitors should be designed and saved as popular graphic formats such as PNG , JPEG and GIF.also gimp is a good lovely tool.